# Why do I have to explicitly define all types with out/ref in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

If I have a delegate defined with `out` keyword like this:

```
delegate int D<TResult, TArgument>(TArgument argument, out TResult result);
```

And I want to set it up with a lambda expression, it has to be like this:

```
        D<int, int> d = (int arg, out int rst) =>{...} //correct
```

The following two statements are **wrong**:

```
        D<int, int> d1 = ( arg, out rst) => {...} //CS2046

        D<int, int> d2 = (arg, out int rst) => {...} //CS0748
```

So my question is: Why does C# design like this? I understand that you have to claim `out` in order to be clear and be able to overload. But it is clear that `rst` and `arg` has to be `int`. Why Do I have to define all of them? [CS0748](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0748) tells me not to do this but no why.

In my mind this is what it should be. Is there any exception that can cause problem on this?

```
D<int, int> d1 = ( arg, out rst) => {...} ////won't compile
```

**Update**

Looks like this issue is still under discussion in C# design group. There are a bunch of proposals around this open issue in the official C# language design repo [#338](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/338).

Comment: because you have to provide a formal parameter to delegate definition and you are trying to pass actual parameter instead.

Comment: @er-sho Sorry I don't get your point. Can you be more specific?

Comment: "it is clear that `rst` and `arg` has to be `int`" - why do you say so?

Comment: The answer is because the CLR teams had to make trade-offs when designing language features, the compiler needs to know the types at this point in time in this situation, additionally they chose to implement it like this

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because `D` delegate define as `D<int,int>` it gives this information. If without `out` keyword, you will see that ` D<int, int> d = ( arg, rst) => {...}` compile. It can't be any other type, because it is defined as ` D<int, int>`

Comment: But mistake your making is believing they made this rule for the fun or it, and there was no reason, lambdas and anonymous types and lots of other language features have lot going on inderneith when complied

Comment: @MichaelRandall If I think they made this rule for fun I won't even ask this question. I just want to know why they decide to make this rule so I can learn from their idea :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears the designers of the C# language decided that there could be strictly two types of anonymous function signatures - these are defined as an *explicit-anonymous-function-signature* and an *implicit-anonymous-function-signature*.

The *explicit-anonymous-function-signature* is a fairly standard parameter list - between the `()` brackets and separated by commas, each parameter definition consists of an optional modifier (`out` or `ref`), a type and an identifier.

The *implicit-anonymous-function-signature* is a drastically simpler parameter list - between the `()` brackets and separated by commas, each parameter definition consists of just an identifier.

You don't get to mix-and-match between the two forms, you have to pick one or the other. This probably makes parsing simpler and makes type inference an off/on concept, not one that is "half-on" (which is what `CS0748` is really saying).

It certainly lets them make other rules within the language easier to specify by being able to talk about lambdas with one or the other type of signature.

And so if you need to include a modifier (`out`) you're out of choices - you have to use the *explicit-anonymous-function-signature*.

---

From C# specification, version 5:

> *lambda-expression*:
>
> - *anonymous-function-signature*   `=>`   *anonymous-function-body*
>
> *anonymous-method-expression*:
>
> - `delegate`   *explicit-anonymous-function-signature*<sub>*opt*</sub>   *block*
>
> *anonymous-function-signature*:
>
> - *explicit-anonymous-function-signature*
> - *implicit-anonymous-function-signature*
>
> *explicit-anonymous-function-signature*:
>
> - `(`   *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*<sub>*opt*</sub>   `)`
>
> *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*:
>
> - *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter*
> - *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*   `,`   *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter*
>
> *explicit-anonymous-function-parameter*:
>
> - *anonymous-function-parameter-modifier*<sub>*opt*</sub>   *type*   *identifier*
>
> *anonymous-function-parameter-modifier*:
>
> - `ref`
> - `out`
>
> *implicit-anonymous-function-signature*:
>
> - `(`   *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*<sub>*opt*</sub>   `)`
> - *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter*
>
> *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*:
>
> - *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter*
> - *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter-list*   `,`   *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter*
>
> *implicit-anonymous-function-parameter*:
>
> - *identifier*

Comment: The thing is that they made it like this, but without a convincing reason, I think it can be improved. This is definitely a compiler issue, not a CLR limit at all. See my update, it's still under discussion.

Comment: @joe - well, *personally* I'm glad we cannot get "accidental `ref`". It's established that any method *may* change it's parameters, however much we may think that a good or bad thing. A Lambda not marked with `ref` doing such a thing and having side-effects elsewhere could be unpleasant.